# If a port is used to connect one service, is it OK to be used to connect another service?

Tags: linux, networking, port

For example, I have a ruby on rails app(10.0.0.3), it will connect redis(10.0.0.4) and mysql(10.0.0.5)

if ror has used 10.0.0.3:12345 to establish a TCP connection to redis(10.0.0.4:6379), can ror use 10.0.0.3:12345 at the same time to connect(TCP) to 10.0.0.5:3306?

I'm confused of srcIP:srcPORT:dstIP:dstPORT, since dst ip is different, so I can use the port??

Comment: the port can only connect to one thing at once, so you can do redis, close, connect mysql.

Comment: That depends on the transport protocols used. If you use TCP for one service, and UDP for the other service, that will work. Ports are transport-layer addresses for some transport protocols, but they are per protocol. TCP `12345` is _not_ the same as UDP `12345`.

Comment: both are TCP in this case

Comment: @pm100 That is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is possible, as a TCP connection is identified by the 4-tuple *{source IP, source port, target IP, target port}.*

However the kernel will probably not actually allow the second and subsequent `bind()` calls using the same local port, as `bind()` precedes `connect()`.